# Heroku terminates worker performing http chunking (streaming)

Tags: python, django, heroku

According to the heroku [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), it allows long responses as long as data is being sent every 55sec.

> Heroku supports HTTP 1.1 features such as long-polling and streaming responses. An application has an initial 30 second window to respond with a single byte back to the client. However, each byte transmitted thereafter (either received from the client or sent by your application) resets a rolling 55 second window. If no >data is sent during the 55 second window, the connection will be terminated.

My the worker app, which is returning a `StreamingHttpResponse` every few seconds, is being terminated after exactly 30sec

```
app[web.1]: [2017-03-24 16:26:24 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:24)
app[web.1]: [2017-03-24 16:26:24 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error     code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/createRepos" host=managegithub.herokuapp.com request_id=96d4d31e-f9ff-46c0-b727-04ca0dfae2a3 fwd="89.127.160.122" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=30690ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https
app[web.1]: [2017-03-24 16:26:25 +0000] [31] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31
```

Why is the worked terminated while it is continually responding with data every few seconds?

Comment: Do you have --keep-alive in your procfile? For example, web: gunicorn info.wsgi --keep-alive 5

Comment: yes: --keep-alive 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `--timeout 300` to the procfile worked.